# JavaScript replace img src with External src

Tags: javascript, image, url, replace, src

I'm having a strange problem that I can't quite figure out.

I have a normal image on a web page

```
<img src="images/logo.png"/>    <!-- getting image from root directory -->
```

and I have some javascript code to replace the image source

```
function imageUpdate() {
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    for (var num = 0; num < image.length; image++)
        image[num].src = image[num].src.replace("images/pic01.png", "images/other/pic02.png")
}
```

This code works fine which is great although it seems to fall down as soon as the src I want it replaced to is outside of my root directory such as "http://www.servername.com/pic03.png" // (this is an imaginary URL don't try to click it).

is there a reason this happens? is there a way around this?

Comment: I have tested that the new img src works

Comment: I am using this url for testing purposes <img src="http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png"/>

Comment: Add `http://www.` to the beginning of your source.

Comment: I have tried it with the following URL http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png

Comment: it looks like it takes out the http://www. inside the comment section but it's definitely there in my code

Comment: I recognize that, but did you add the protocol in my previous comment? So it would be: `http://www.oecd.org...`

Comment: [link]http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png

Comment: sorry Im battling to format what I type in the comment section

Comment: how do I stop it from formatting -_-

Comment: Put tick marks around your code instead, these things here: \`

Comment: 'http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-‌​34x34.png'

Comment: [link](http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-‌​34x34.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only replacing the last part of your original src. The src of the img tag first looks like this:

"http://yourserver.com/images/pic01.png"

...and after replacing "images/pic01.png" with you external URL, it looks like this:

"http://yourserver.com/http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png"

To avoid this problem you can try this:

```js
function imageUpdate() {
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    for (var num = 0; num < image.length; num++) {
        if (stringEndsWith(image[num].src, "images/pic01.png")) {
            image[num].src = "http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png";
        }
    }
}

function stringEndsWith(string, suffix) {
    return string.indexOf(suffix, string.length - suffix.length) !== -1
}
```

There's also an error in your for loop, where you are incrementing image instead of num

**Step-by-step explanation**

*imageUpdate()*
Loop through each img tag and look at the src attribute
If src ends with "images/pic01.png" replace all of src with the new url

*stringEndsWith()*
Find index of given suffix (start looking for the suffix at the last possible position
the suffix can be located at)
If this index is found (is different from -1) return true, else return false

Comment: This works perfectly and I commend you for making sense of my horrible formatted URL

Comment: oh i didn't see the image++ increment (that is just me being an idiot) it isn't like that in my code, my bad

Comment: The more I read this code the more it impresses (and confuses) me. I'm very grateful that it works but I hate using a code that I do not understand, can I be a complete noob and ask you to go through it for me?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Johan, you're a javascript blackbelt

Comment: I added one small change

Answer (score 0):

What target url are you assigning to it? Make sure that it is pointing to an absolute address (keep the http:// part at the beginning).

If the file is in the same server, you can still use relative file paths, and go up a parent folder by using two dots. For instance: ../someotherfolder/pic03.jpg

Comment: oww, just no ... client side requests should be an url, not relative path.

Comment: I am using this URL for testing purposes <img src="http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png"/> just to make sure it works

Comment: it doesnt like the image tag in the comment http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png there, just so you can see it's not a URL problem

Comment: in your earlier comment with the img tag, you didn't include http://, so is it possible that you're not using a well-formed url in the other code?

Comment: im using this URL --  h.t.tp://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png // I added the fullstops coz the comment section keeps formatting that part out

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

function imageUpdate() {

    document.getElementById('imageT').src = 'test.jpg';

}

</script>

<img id='imageT' src="images/logo.png"/>    <!-- getting image from root directory -->
```

[JS Fiddle-Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/RxrSh/9/)

Comment: The code is working for changing the img src it only stops working when the URL is beginning with     http://www.

Comment: Im using this URL h.t.tp://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png // i added random fullstops coz the comment section keeps formatting out that part

Comment: uri is invalid , please check it

Comment: any way the URL is right it works everywhere except when it is being replaced, it will show up as the "x" when an image URL is wrong although the URL is right I just dont know if the javascript is putting it into source as a string and not a URL or something like that

Comment: Its only invalid because i put two full stops in the h.t.tp part, take those out and it will work

Comment: sorry you were right the one in the comment is wrong, sorry this comment formatting is killing me, how do i keep it from formatting my comments?

Comment: I added a plus sign -> h+ttp://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png

Comment: A slightly modified jsfiddle demo i provided , please check

Comment: your code works nicely but not in this situation but this is a nice quick way to change other sources that I can use, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the link you are trying to use. The actual link should be:

```
http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png
```

Here is come code to demonstrate:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById('changeThis').src = 'http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png'
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="changeThis" src="http://www.wartburgseminary.edu/uploadedImages/Resources/small-twitter-icon.jpg">
<input type="button" value="Change" onClick="changeImage()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the formatting in the comment section keeps breaking my link, how do I write a url in the comment section that will not get formatted?

Comment: When trying to show the code for a link, do not use \[\]\(\) syntax, that will actually create a link. Instead, to make "code" use these marks \` around code. Also, when you are creating a comment, there is a help link next to the comment box. That will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: oh my god no wonder, I thought those were quotation marks ' instead of `

Comment: `http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png`

Comment: `http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png`

Comment: Haha, it's all good. Anyways, if you took the above code and ran it, it works just fine.

Comment: `http://www.oecd.org/media/oecdorg/directorates/developmentcentre/Facebook-logo-34x34.png`

Comment: sorry I'm battling with getting what I want into the comment section but just trust me the URL is right XD just a quick question but do you know why it wouldn't work with the javascript in my question?

Comment: Try this. If you copy paste the link you just put two comments above and enter it into the browser. You will be sent to a "page not found" page. There is something wrong with your link. However, if you take the link I provided in my answer, and copy paste that into a browser, it takes you to the icon you want.

Comment: yeah the comment section is adding spaces (I have no idea why) where it goes on to a new line, the link is right but it is breaking in the comment section